# GtkLevelBar Orientation

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm working on a GTK+ project, and I need a vertical GtkLevelBar like this:

[image]

But i cannot figure out how to flip it from the default horizontal GtkLevelBar:

[image]

Here is my code for the GtkLevelBar.

```
GtkWidget * levelBar    = gtk_level_bar_new ( );

gtk_level_bar_set_max_value (
    GTK_LEVEL_BAR ( levelBar ),
    32767 );

gtk_level_bar_set_min_value (
    GTK_LEVEL_BAR ( levelBar ),
    0 );

gtk_level_bar_set_mode (
   GTK_LEVEL_BAR ( levelBar ),
   GtkLevelBarMode::GTK_LEVEL_BAR_MODE_CONTINUOUS );

gtk_box_pack_start (
   GTK_BOX ( this -> boxLeft ( )),
   levelBar,
   TRUE,
   TRUE,
   0 );

gtk_widget_show ( levelBar );
```

Where `this -> boxLeft ( )` is a getter for a `GtkBox`.

How do I change the orientation of the GtkLevelBar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GtkLevelBar implements [GtkOrientable](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Orientable.html#GtkOrientable), so:

```
gtk_orientable_set_orientation (GTK_ORIENTABLE (levelBar),
                                GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
```

Comment: in PyGObject you can use  `.set_orientation(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)`.